# in which c++ Class can I find cv::findChessboardCorners()

Tags: c++, opencv

does anyone know if the function
 `cv::findChessboardCorners()`in OpenCV  is implemented in a c++ class if yes please which one
thanks

Comment: I know how to use the function and that wasn't my question I want to know the class name  if there's one so I can extend it in my program

Comment: Yeah, I noticed it later and removed my comment.

Comment: I am pretty sure it is a non-member function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  #include <opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp>  ( L170 )
```

Comment: that the header file, I'm asking about the class

Comment: there is no class, it is a free function

Comment: ok, seems i got you wrong as well. but again : there's no class to inherit, and nothing to extend here.

Answer (score 1):

I found the location of the script from [this link](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/calib3d/src/calibinit.cpp) in Signal Processing Stack Exchange as existing in the file [calib3d/src/calibinit.cpp](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/calib3d/src/calibinit.cpp) on line 424.

```
CV_IMPL
int cvFindChessboardCorners( const void* arr, CvSize pattern_size,
                             CvPoint2D32f* out_corners, int* out_corner_count,
                             int flags )
```

The answer includes a description of the process involved in the function as:

> 1. Use cvCheckChessboard to determine if a chessboard is in the image
> 2. Convert to binary (B&W) and dilate to split the corners apart
> 3. Use icvGenerateQuads to find the squares.
>
> The code then seems to go though a set of checks to condense these
>   quads to chessboard corners, including icvFindConnectedQuads,
>   icvCleanFoundConnectedQuads to remove extra corners,
>   icvCheckQuadGroup, and icvCheckBoardMonotony.
>
> All of these functions are implemented in the same file, apart from
>   cvCheckChessboard which is in [calib3d/src/checkchessboard.cpp](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/calib3d/src/checkchessboard.cpp).
>   Depending how well you wanted to understand the code, there seem to be
>   a number of debugging lines, which can be included if you #define
>   DEBUG_CHESSBOARD, that may help you see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Source code is found in the opencv archive at `opencv/modules/calib3d/src/calibinit.cpp` line 219. Take a quick look [here](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/modules/calib3d/src/calibinit.cpp?rev=3216).

```
int cvFindChessboardCorners( const void* arr, CvSize pattern_size,
                             CvPoint2D32f* out_corners, int* out_corner_count,
                             int flags )
{
 ....
}
```

Comment: again! I already and the source code, and a debug it line by line and I was looking for a class that uses or implement this method as well, so I can extend. the and is what @Juanchopanza gives I can't accept it because it's a comment

Comment: Huh? This is a perfectly valid answer to your question.